# Can't copy special characters outside of vim

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard, encoding

I'm using `NVIM v0.4.3` with `set clipboard=unnamed`. I can insert special character like `üäö` in vim just fine, but if I copy content containing special characters in vim and try to paste them outside of vim they appear as garbage. Yanking/pasting inside of vim works just fine.

**Examples:**

- inside nvim "über" becomes "√ºber" outside
- inside nvim "äffchen" become √§ffchen outside

**Further Information:**
I'm running neovim in iTerm2 (zsh) on macOS Catalina.

Comment: Which OS? Are you running nvim in a Terminal (if so, which?) or a GUI version of nvim such as nvim-qt?

Comment: @filbranden See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your locale contains the full UTF8 specification to a language; i.e. not something like `en_US`, but `en_US.UTF-8`.  See [this issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/11432).

Comment: Thank you! This did fix my problem. I added `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to my `.zshrc`.